# Having two Model in One PMML File

Tags: r, pmml

Can we have **two or more model** in one PMML file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ["general structure" section of the PMML specification](https://dmg.org/pmml/v4-4-1/GeneralStructure.html), the root `PMML` element can contain zero or more child model elements.

Therefore, you can easily have two (or twenty) **top-level model elements** in your PMML file.

Comment: Hey can you provide me with a sample file having two models in it, As I am entirely new to this.

Comment: CAN ONE ONE PROVIDE ME ONE SAMPLE FILE CONTAINING TWO MODELS IN IT